# Printed unsigned chars as hex are too long

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets assume I have this very simple example:

```
vector<unsigned char> bytes {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD};

for (const char & v: bytes) {
    cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << uppercase << static_cast<unsigned>(v) <<" ";
}

cout << endl;
```

This gives:

```
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFD
```

However, I would like to have it short, like:

```
FF FF FD
```

So why do I get some many extra "FFFFF"?

Comment: you're casting your values to `unsigned int`, which is 32bit

Comment: Without casting i get this: 0� 0� 0� Only some strange characters, not hex.

Comment: The cast is fine. the problem is the conversion to `char`, which is probably signed on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (const char & v: bytes)
```

You're implicitly converting each element in `bytes` to a `char`, which seems to be `signed` on your platform. Then when you cast to `unsigned` the `char` undergoes sign extension and you end up with large hex values.

Change the above to one of the following

```
for (const unsigned char & v: bytes)
for (auto const& v: bytes)
for (auto v: bytes) // since it's only a char copying might be better
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741928a553f793c8)

Comment: I might have just gone with `auto v` since it's just a `char`.

Comment: @T.C. I think that covers all options

Answer (score 3):

You get the desired result if you keep the `char` unsigned in the loop:

```
for (const unsigned char & v: bytes) {
    //     ^^^^^^^^
    cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << uppercase << static_cast<unsigned>(v) <<" ";
}
```

`auto` or `auto&` would work as well, because vector elements are unsigned.

The reason you get `FF`s is that `char` on your system is *signed*, meaning that the values get sign-extended on conversion to integers.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/hTSidF)

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, this happens because you're casting the elements to a signed char. I prefer using a for loop in this way to prevent such mistakes:

```
vector<unsigned char> bytes{ 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD };

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
    cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << uppercase << static_cast<unsigned>(bytes[i]) << " ";
}
```

Using iterators would also be a good idea.